# Specflow obtain all steps in current scenario using BeforeScenario hook

Tags: c#, specflow

I'd like to be able to get a list of the steps that a scenario is about to run in `BeforeScenario` hook, because I want to parse the steps and run some preliminary actions based on what the steps are. But using `ScenarioContext` only gives basic info (e.g. scenario title, tags, etc.). Is there any way to get the steps about to be run? Maybe some way through `System.Reflection`? I tried `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`, but it returns an empty string array.

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem you are trying to solve? I suspect that running silent logic based on steps in your scenario has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow doesn't have this information at runtime available.

The only thing you could do is to parse the feature file again and look there for
We include all feature files as resources in the test assembly.

Like this:
[image]